# How to enable local image registry on OpenShift Single Node Cluster installation

Tags: devops, openshift, openshift-4

I've recently completed an installation of a Single Node Cluster using OpenShift 4 but I'm running into issues when trying to spin up some of the example container / projects they have available. I just keep getting the following error:

```
Error starting build: an image stream cannot be used as build output because the integrated container image registry is not configured
```

It doesn't seem to matter which of the template containers I choose, I always get the same error.
Obviously I could be wrong here, but I'm guessing this has something to do with the local registry not being enabled or configured correctly yet? Assuming that's the case, how do I go about configuring the image registry on a Single Node Cluster?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

"because the integrated container image registry is not configured"

Quick Solution with ephemeral storage (no storage class for persistence):

```
oc project openshift-image-registry
```

```
oc edit configs.imageregistry.operator.openshift.io
```

```
...
  managementState: Managed
...
...
  replica: 1
...
...
  storage:
    emptyDir: {}
```

```
oc get pods
```

You can then also expose the registry:

```
oc patch configs.imageregistry.operator.openshift.io/cluster --patch '{"spec":{"defaultRoute":true}}' --type=merge
```

```
oc get routes
```

Answer (score 0):

PS I mentioned exposing the route becuase you can then log into the registry and tag/push you'r own images for deployment with:

```
podman login -u user -p $(oc whoami -t) --tls-verify=false default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.yourdomain.com
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).